# How to iterate over the class objects and change the property value in Python

Tags: python

I have the following two classes MasterProgramList and ProgramList.
MasterProgramList takes in a json array object which is defined below in the usage code.
I am trying to iterate over each Program object and change the start_date property.
When I do so, the value does not change but stays as what is defined in the json array object.
Is there something wrong with my ProgramList/Program class? How can I iterate over the class objects and change the property value?

MasterProgramList.py

```
import json
import datetime
class MasterProgramList(object):
    def __init__(self, program_list, today=None):
        self.program_list = [ProgramList(program) for program in program_list]
        self.today = today

    def current_programs(self):
        if self.today is not None:
            def filter_if_between_start_and_end(program):
                return (datetime.datetime.strptime(program.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()) <= self.today.date() <= (
                        datetime.datetime.strptime(program.end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date())

                program_list = self.program_list
                for x in program_list:
                    x.programs = filter(filter_if_between_start_and_end, x.programs)

                filtered_program_list = program_list
            else:
                filtered_program_list = self.program_list
            return filtered_program_list
```

ProgramList.py

```
class ProgramList(object):
    """
    CRM-specific version of the ProgramList Configuration object
    """
    def __init__(self, config):
        self._config = config
        self.brand = config['brand']
        self.programs = self._parse_programs(config['brand'], config['programs'])

    def _parse_programs(cls, brand, program_list):
        return [Program.from_json(brand, p) for p in program_list]

class Program(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._config = kwargs.get('config') #required json data
        self.name = kwargs.get('name') #required json data
        self.start_date = kwargs.get('start_date') #required json data
        self.end_date = kwargs.get('end_date') #required json data

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._config)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, brand, program_json):
        program_json['name'] = '{0}_{1}'.format(brand.capitalize(), program_json['name'])
        program_json['department'] = 'CRM'
        return Program(
            config = program_json,
            name = program_json['name'],
            start_date = program_json['start_date'],
            end_date = program_json['end_date']
        )
```

Usage:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

crm_program_master_list = [
    {
        "brand": "testbrand",
        "programs": [
            {
                "name": "Program1",
                "start_date": "2020-01-02",
                "end_date": "2999-12-31"
            },
            {
                "name": "Program2",
                "start_date": "2020-01-04",
                "end_date": "2999-12-31"
            }
        ]
    }
]

today_date = (datetime.strptime('2020-01-06', '%Y-%m-%d'))
crm_programs_to_analyze = MasterProgramList(crm_program_master_list, today=today_date)
crm_programs_to_analyze.program_list = crm_programs_to_analyze.current_programs()

programs = []
for x in crm_programs_to_analyze.program_list:
    for p in x.programs:
        #change the start_date for each program
        p.start_date = '2020-01-22'
        print('program: {}'.format(p))
        programs.append(p)
```

```
output:
program: {'name': 'Program1', 'end_date': '2999-12-31', 'department': 'CRM', 'start_date': '2020-01-02'}
program: {'name': 'Program2', 'end_date': '2999-12-31', 'department': 'CRM', 'start_date': '2020-01-04'}

expected output:
program: {'name': 'Program1', 'end_date': '2999-12-31', 'department': 'CRM', 'start_date': '2020-01-22'}
program: {'name': 'Program2', 'end_date': '2999-12-31', 'department': 'CRM', 'start_date': '2020-01-22'}
```

Comment: @Z4-tier yes it was an indentation error. i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few things to clean up to make this work:

In the Usage section, there are no imports for `ProgramList` or `MasterProgramList`. I added them as:

```
from MasterProgramList import MasterProgramList
from ProgramList import ProgramList
```

then, in `MasterProgramList.py` I added an import of `ProgramList`.

Moving on, I see that `crm_programs_to_analyze.program_list` is a list that contains one `ProgramList.ProgramList` object. So your outer `for` loop is iterating once on that single object. Then the inner `for` loop iterates over the members of the `ProgramList`'s programs, and there it is setting the `start_date` to `2020-01-22`.

The problem you are having is in the `__repr__` method-- specifically where it's getting the values it returns. Here is a very short example that illustrates the problem:

```
>>> class f:
...   def __init__(self, config):
...     self.config = config
...     self.start_date = config['start_date']
...     self.end_date = config['end_date']
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return str(self.config)
...
>>> conf = {'start_date': '2020-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'}
>>> foo = f(conf)
>>> foo
{'start_date': '2020-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'}
>>> foo.start_date = '2019-10-10' # <-- Changes start_date, but not config
>>> foo
{'start_date': '2020-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'} # <-- From config
>>> foo.start_date # <-- but this as updated as expected
'2019-10-10'
>>> foo.config
{'start_date': '2020-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'} # <-- unchanged
>>> foo.config['start_date'] = foo.start_date
>>> foo
{'start_date': '2019-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'}
>>> foo.start_date
'2019-10-10'
>>> foo.config # <-- now it's changed and they match
{'start_date': '2019-10-10', 'end_date': '2021-12-03'}
```

The value of `start_date` *is* being updated. But printing `p` by way of the `__repr__` is getting the original value from `_config`, which isn't updated when `p.start_date` is modified. To fix it, either add in an update to change the `start_date` in `p._config`, or have `__repr__` return the value of `start_date` instead.

Like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        rv = f'Start Date: {self.start_date}, End Date: {self.end_date}, Config: '
        for k, v in self._config.items():
            rv += f'{k} : {v}, '
        return rv
```

Comment: thanks for your help i ended up doing 
    def __repr__(self):
        data = {}
        data['name'] = self.name
        data['start_date'] = self.start_date
        data['end_date'] = self.end_date
        data['source'] = self.source
        data['department'] = self.department
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return str(json_data)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code.  Let's deal with the first problem.

```
class MasterProgramList(object):
    def __init__(self, program_list, today=None):
        #ProgramList is a class, not a function.  It has no return value.  
        self.program_list = [ProgramList(program) for program in program_list]
        self.today = today

    #do not define function after conditional logic.  
    def filter_if_between_start_and_end(self, program):
        return (datetime.datetime.strptime(program.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()) <= self.today.date() <= (
                    datetime.datetime.strptime(program.end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date())

    def current_programs(self):
        if self.today is not None:
            program_list = self.program_list
            for x in program_list:
                x.programs = filter(self.filter_if_between_start_and_end(x.programs))

            filtered_program_list = program_list
        else:
            filtered_program_list = self.program_list
        return filtered_program_list
```